# What Encoding to set for iTextSharp Romanian language

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf, itext

I try to create a PDF file with iTextSharp version 5.5.9.0 (I added from NuGet). All works fine but not and Romanian diacritics (**ȘșȚțăĂÂâ**). I read a lot of articles with solutions about that but nothing work. Now I founded a solution that from all diacritics appear only **"ăĂÂâ**" others not appear.
That is my code:

```
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, False)
Dim normalFont As New iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 9, Font.NORMAL)
Dim par As New Paragraph("ȘșȚțăĂÂâ", normalFont)
pdfDoc.Add(par)
```

Can anybody write me what encoding I must write to have all Romanian diacritics.

**Solution:** from "Paulo Soares" is right. I made only some correction.
I downloaded one font that support Romanian language from this site:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/romanian/ than I loaded it on myBaseFont with encoding **BaseFont.IDENTITY_H**
Here is the code:

```
Dim ttfPath As String = "C:\Test\DejaVuSerif.ttf" 'Path to font file
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ttfPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, False)
Dim normalFont As New iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in fonts like `BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN`don't have the Romanian diacritics. You'll need an external font like times.ttf:

```
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, True)
```