# Romanian characters not working with ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to convert an html to pdf using **ITextSharp** library version 5.5.13.2. For some reason, the Romanian special characters (`ș`, `ț`, `ă`, `î`, `â`) that exists inside the html are omitted and does not appear in the pdf file. Could you please help me?

```
var htmlString = "Some html string containing romanian characters";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Format.Invariant(htmlString));
Stream reader = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);

document.AddTitle(PdfTitle);
document.AddSubject(PdfSubject);
document.AddAuthor(PdfAuthor);
document.AddCreator(PdfCreator);
document.AddKeywords(PdfKeyWords);

document.Open();

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader, null, Encoding.Unicode, new TimesNewRomanUnicodeFontFactory());

document.Close();
```

And my `TimesNewRomanUnicodeFontFactory` is like this:

```
private class TimesNewRomanUnicodeFontFactory : FontFactoryImp
    {
        private readonly BaseFont _baseFont;

        public TimesNewRomanUnicodeFontFactory()
        {
            _baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        }  
    }
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442332/what-encoding-to-set-for-itextsharp-romanian-language/37443034

Comment: The problem is the PDF format itself, not iTextSharp. PDF is essentially ASCII. To use  non-ASCII text you need to encode the text *and* use a font that covers the language you want. That's why there are *dozens* of questions like [Unicode in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128162/unicode-in-pdf) and [How to write UTF-8 characters to a pdf file using itextsharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110311/how-to-write-utf-8-characters-to-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp). Libraries like iText and iTextSharp take care of encoding, but you still need the font

Comment: In your case, you just need to load the `Times New Roman` font that comes with Windows. All TrueType and OpenType fonts on Windows are Unicode even if they don't cover *every* available character. Almost all of them include glphs for the `Latin Extended-B` range which includes Romanian characters.

Comment: Thanks all for the input. I've tried to add the base font that comes from Windows _baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\times.ttf", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); but the outcome is the same (romanian characters does not appear)